# Swftui custom shape

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to draw a figure for a tab bar like this for a very long time
[image]

I try this method for drawing this tabbar shape

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
 
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().frame(height: 83)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
                .frame(width: 59, height: 59).padding(.bottom, 59 + 24)//.padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

But that's not what I need.
I tried drawing with Curve path, but no results. Can someone explain how to properly draw such a tab bar?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Shape`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, I did draw shape with curve

Comment: You should post that effort here, because that is probably the best way to do it and somebody can help you tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

YES! I managed to write the correct form!
If anyone needs it, here's the code

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    
    let radius: CGFloat = 14.0
    
    private let padding: CGFloat = 31.5
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        var path = Path()
        
        path.move(to: .zero)
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - padding - radius, y: rect.minY))
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - padding, y: rect.minY + radius),
                          control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - padding, y: rect.minY))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - padding,
                                 y: rect.minY + padding - radius))
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - padding + radius,
                                      y: rect.minY + padding),
                          control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - padding,
                                           y: rect.minY + padding))
        

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + padding - radius,
                                 y: rect.minY + padding))
        
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + padding,
                                      y: rect.minY + padding - radius),
                          control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + padding, y: rect.minY + padding))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + padding,
                                 y: rect.minY + radius))
                
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + padding + radius, y: rect.minY),
                          control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + padding, y: rect.minY))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        
        return path
    }
    
}
```

[image]